# Bootstrap 3 - Link in Load table with json

Tags: javascript, json, bootstrap-table

I have a website that loads a table using the Table Bootstrap plugin and I'm loading the table using json

```
 [{
     "col1": "<a href='#' id"link-row">Juan Martinez Chavarria</a>"
 }]
```

The problem is that I need to invoke the onclick event of the element "a" through "id" attribute.

```
 $("#link-row").click(function () {
     alert("Hello");
 });
```

Calling the event, I have it in an external js file, but I can not access the event or are ignoring the js file and does not display the alert.

Please, how I can access a js event from a link, of a table loaded with json?

In addition, the accents of the json file, do not look at the website, they are show coded. How I can resolve this?

Comment: Can you provide us with a jsfiddle to make it easier to understand the question?

Comment: first of all check your json, because i see you are using double quote both for element tag and for the json string. then you have to use "on" not "click" since the element is created after the dom is loaded you need to delegate. jquery provide it by default using "on" see my answer and demo

Answer (score 1):

Dynamically created content cant be targeted by that selector, use this:

```
 $("#yourTable tbody").click("#link-row",function () {
     alert("Hello");
 });
```

Could be better to use a class instead an id to manage this type of events

Answer (score 1):

> - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/eaebyLzx/

```
$(function () {

    var links = [{
        "col1": '<a href="#" id="link-row">Juan Martinez Chavarria</a>'
    }];

    $.each(links, function (i, item) {
        $('table tbody').append('<tr><td>' + item.col1 + '</td></tr>');
    });

    $('#link-row').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert(this.id)
    });
});
```